# Thread priority does not work as expected?

Tags: java, multithreading, interface, thread-priority

i made a program using Thread priority and i got the same number of clicks for both thread with priority 1 and thread with priority 10 , its confusing why i am getting this

```
class clicker implements Runnable {
    int click = 0;
    Thread t;
    private volatile boolean running = true;
    public clicker(int p) {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.setPriority(p);
    }
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            click++;
        }
    }
    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }
    public void start() {
        t.start();
    }
}

class hilopri {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        clicker hi = new clicker(1);
        clicker lo = new clicker(10);
        lo.start();
        hi.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
        }
        lo.stop();
        hi.stop();
        // Wait for child threads to terminate.
        try {
            hi.t.join();
            lo.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
        }
        System.out.println("Low-priority thread: " + lo.click);
        System.out.println("High-priority thread: " + hi.click);
    }
}
```

the output is almost the same regardless of the priority

```
Low-priority thread: 322141133
High-priority thread: 477591649
```

Comment: High priority has ~48% more than low-priority - hardly the same?

Comment: Thread priority is highly dependent on the OS and what user is running the program. What OS?

Comment: @EvanKnowles when i change the priority , the o/p remains the same

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the behavior of *Thread Priority* isn't guaranteed. Changing the priority is just a hint / suggestion to the underlying OS that can be totally ignored. A thread with low priority can get more CPU cycles than a thread with high priority. So, bottom line- don't write critical code based on Thread priority.

Answer (score 0):

What @TheLostMind told you is all true, but here's something else to consider.

If your computer has more CPUs than you have runnable threads, then *all* of the runnable threads are going to be allowed to run.  Priority (if it matters at all) can only matter when the threads are in contention for a scarce resource.